# htaccess infinite loop numbers

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Thanks for help me! :)

I have the next Url: www.domain.com/folder/123-321-something.html

The redirection should be www.domain.com/folder/321-something-123.html

I have the next htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*/)([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/$1$3-$2.html? [R=301,L]
```

And the result of this URL is

The redirection should be www.domain.com/folder/something-123-321.html

I don't know how can execute the rule only one time to avoid the loop.

Also I have one URL with  www.domain.com/folder/123-321.html that result in a infinite loop.

I read about

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

And I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*/)([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/$1$3-$2.html? [R=301,L]
```

But don't work.

I hope an answer to solution this issue.

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand what you need. To make this simple. What is the original URL you have and what is the new URL you want to redirect to? And then what is `something` is that word, number, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the result for me was the {REQUEST_URI} directive.

When a Url have the concrete numbers with "-" plus id_product_numbers at the end of the url, the rewrite condition skips and don't falls into infinite loops

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*/)(1|3|5|7|24|212|4711|1881)-([0-9]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*/)([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/$1$3-$2.html? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works fine when I do a test run. I added the domain to the left and it seems to stop before it loops because of the R flag you already have in place.

`RewriteRule ^www.domain.com/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*/)([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html$ www.domain.com/$1$3-$2.html [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

This rule will work for you by avoiding the loop:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*-[a-z]+)\.html$ /$1/$3-$2.html? [R=301,L,NC]
```